# Parametric constructors

Tags: julia, parametric-polymorphism

I am having some issues understanding the concept of parametric constructors in Julia. I am looking at the standard example in the Julia docs:

```
struct Point{T<:Real}
    x::T
    y::T
end
```

To my understanding, this means I can generate a Point-datatype with an input that is subtype of Real, i.e., AbstractFloat, AbstractIrrational, ..., Integer, Rational, ..., StatsBase.TestStat.

However, both of the examples below result in errors:

```
Point(Integer(12))
Point(Rational(12))
```

Why does the above fail given that both integer and rational are subtypes of real?

Comment: did you read the part about parametric types being invariant?

Comment: @Empress.Svetlana Yes. When I add the subtype operator `<:`, to my understanding I am making sure that the input can be any subtype of `Real` (?)

Comment: Right, but `Point{Real}` isn't a Subtype of `Real`. When you declare, you have to declare it like this: `p = Point{Integer}(12,12)`

Comment: @Empress.Svetlana Thanks. but where in my example above am I assuming that `Point{Real}` is a subtype of `Real`? I am only assuming that `Integer` and `Rational` are subtypes of `Real` - or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: :D. You are misunderstanding something here.

Comment: `Point(Integer(12))` calls a _two argument_ constructor with _one_ argument. Are you sure that't not the error you see? Or is there some additional code you didn't show?

Comment: @phipsgabler You're right, that was merely it. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Using `Integer(12)` is not a problem since `Integer(12)` just makes an `Int64` (you cannot create an instance of an abstract type.) The real problem is that you supply only _one_ input, when the constructor requires _two_. So in your case `Point(12, 13)` will work, no need for a type parameter in the constructor, unless you want the type parameter to be abstract.

Comment: @DNF In an attempt to create a Real, I tried `typeof(Real(12.3))` which just returns `Float64`. I guess this is due to us not being able to create instances of abstract types as you write. But what is the reason for this? And how do I create a Real with value 12.3 then?

Comment: That's the definition of an abstract type: it's a type that cannot have any concrete instances (hence the name 'abstract', if you could instantiate it, it wouldn't be abstract, by definition!) It only exists to be subtyped. This is not particular to Julia, and is the same in all languages with types. And it's the same with languages with classes: abstract classes cannot be instantiated. So you cannot create a value with type `Real`, but 12.3 will still be a `Real` in the sense that its type is a subtype of `Real`, so `12.3 isa Real` returns `true`.

Comment: You _can_ create containers with `Real` as `eltype`, though. That will be a container that can hold elements with several different types simultaneously, like `Real[1, 2.5]`. So each element has a concrete type that must be a subtype of `Real`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  type parameter goes inside the curly braces in the constructor call, just like it does in the `struct` definition:

```
julia> Point{Integer}(12, 12)
Point{Integer}(12, 12)

julia> Point{Rational}(12, 10//3)
Point{Rational}(12//1, 10//3)
```

The arguments supplied are the values for the fields of the struct i.e. `x` and `y`. If the arguments are already of the type you want, you can leave out explicitly specifying the type parameter:

```
julia> Point(12, 6)
Point{Int64}(12, 6)

julia> Point(12.0, 6.0)
Point{Float64}(12.0, 6.0)


julia> Point(12, 6.0) #no automatic type promotion happens though
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Point(::Int64, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  Point(::T, ::T) where T<:Real at REPL[1]:2
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ REPL[9]:1

julia> Point{Float64}(12, 6.0) #unless you explicitly specify the type
Point{Float64}(12.0, 6.0)
```